# Subdomain in Zend Framework for specific action

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I need hostname route for only one action. I have this route:

```
$toRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'www.:object.mydomain.dev',
    array(
        'controller' => 'place',
        'action' => 'show',
        'object' => 'somethink')
    );

$router->addRoute('object-page', $toRoute);
```

When I go to place action and redirect from here to other actions, there still is my hostname in URL. E.g if I go to `www.hotelplatinum.mydomain.dev` and there redirect to place/all I get:

```
www.hotelplatinum.mydomain.dev/place/all
```

but I would like:

`www.mydomain.dev/place/all`.

I would like this route works for only one action (show).

I read about chains, but I don't understand this. 
My Zend version is `1.12`.